# Shell Script itself killing own running script process id

Tags: shell, aix, pid, kill-process

I am using below command to get the pid  . "A" is application name and used as parameter. I run my script like ./stop A

```
PID=`ps -ef | grep A| grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}'`
```

This is capturing " **/bin/ksh ./stop A** " process as well .But that I do not want.
I only want process of "**A**" to be captured not my script process in **PID**/

I have below kill command under my script that is killing my running script :(

```
kill -9 $PID
```

It is killing pid of  `/bin/ksh ./stop A` itself also and script is getting stopped at that point .

This is for AIX. How to avoid killing the script itself.

NOTE: When i am working with the same script to do same work but without passing argument it is going good. I believe its obvious as passing an argument to script is creating other pid and for the same application its doing grep and killing.

Comment: You could make the `grep` search unique by `-w`, `ps -ef | grep -w "A" | grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}'` ?

Comment: Not working in AIX . It is still capturing the script process itself and killing it.

Answer (score 1):

If the stop A is the script from what you are calling the kill, you could do

```
for p in $PID
do
   test $p -ne $$ && kill -9 $p
done
```

Note that all other Processes containing an A are still at risk, you might add grep `-w` A to limit to those where the A is a single word

**Edit** or without a loop

```
kill -9 $( ps -ef|grep -w A |grep -v -w $$ | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' )
```

(The grep -v grep should be unneccessary here)

Comment: Can we do like this.
1) Capture the pid by PID=`ps -ef | grep A| grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}'`
2) And in the 1st step itself do a -ne $$ ? so that the script pid itself will not save in "PID"

Comment: you mean without a loop? But if the outcome of your ps ... is two pids, what then? It's always fulfilling the `-ne` and will kill both

Comment: aaah klickediclick - you mean like `ps -ef|grep -w A |grep -v grep|grep -v -w $$ | awk ... ` I think that should be possible too! not too bad

Comment: Not within loop . I mean only to discard that pid in the line 
PID=ps -ef | grep A| grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}' itself >

This will be really helpful if done and  unnecessarily we don't have to put other logic to filter that.

Comment: see comment and edit - without loop and pulling the $$ pid out right in the grep's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114138/discussion-between-rishua-and-stefan-hegny).

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility called `pidof` which lists PIDs of instances of a program with given name. It's available on most Linux machines, so maybe it's also available on AIX?

From the man page:

```
Pidof finds the process id's (pids) of the named programs.
It prints those id's on the standard output.
```

also:

```
When pidof is invoked with a full pathname to the program
it should find the pid of, it is reasonably safe.
Otherwise it is possible that  it  returns  pids  of running
programs  that  happen to have the same name as the program
you're after but are actually other programs.
```

Comment: Not available in AIX.

Comment: It is killing right pids unless i am using that script without parameter . But to make it more generic i added the parameter options. After that I am getting this issue. My script is very long and it has do other multiple things related to my application. :(

Comment: @RishuA: What is wrong the option I suggested? To help you out further, can you tell me what is the output when you manually run command `ps -ef | grep -w "A" | grep -v grep ` It should return the process-id of only the process `A`

Comment: @Inian, Let me explain you . When you run any script with parameter it will generate a pid for itself also. As in this case my parameter is A and I am grepping A . So it is capturing pid of my "./script A " also and when we are using -w "A" it will still capture the script pid as the script is run by parameter "A" itself. For reference output :

XXX11075780 10879170   0 06:18:11  pts/3  0:00 /bin/ksh ./stop.sh A

Comment: Ok, agreed, could use `pgrep`, can you see if  `pgrep -f "A"` is returning the application `A`'s pid? because `pgrep` works on `regex`'s. e.g. `pgrep -f "ssh"`

Comment: As I mentioned I am using AIX , so i have very limited options :) No pgrep available . In freeware I can do with multiple options but AIX is giving me trouble , getting new learning. My environment is AIX and AIX admin manages the OS. I am from application team.